# Hybris : How to give Sort Provider for one of facet attribute using Impex

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Hybris is providing Solr Sort Property for facet value. I can see in HMC for every solr item property, we can set its sorting behavior.

[image]

I want to set this sort by impex. There is a attribute `customFacetSortProvider` (String Type) which is holding the value of selected provider, becuase of String Type what i have to give in Impex so that it will work.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give bean id name in Impex to select `customFacetSortProvider`.

For Example

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;name[unique=true];displayName[lang=en];customFacetSortProvider
;Brand;Brand;facetNameSortProviderAscending
```

`facetNameSortProviderAscending` bean is referring to the "Sort by displayed name" provider. you can check this bean definition in solrfacetsearch-spring.xml file.

```
<bean id="facetNameSortProviderAscending" class="de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.config.impl.DefaultFacetSortProvider">
    <property name="comparator" ref="facetDisplayNameComparator"/>
    <property name="descending" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Like that based on your need, you can give the bean for the respective provider and changes will refelect in HMC as well.

Check [this.](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Customized+Sort+Providers)